# Difference in image size captured from webcam using Python and MATLAB

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, size, image-capture

I often switch between Python and MATLAB during analysis phase of my code development, this time when I was trying to access a specific coordinates of a picture captured from webcam using a simple MATLAB and Python script, I realized that the image size for the same picture (captured from same webcam but with different code (MATLAB and Python)) is different. Same picture in MATLAB was of size `(720, 1280, 3)` and in Python was `(480, 640, 3)`. Any explanation to this will be really helpful!

Please find the code I used for MATLAB and Python below:

MATLAB:

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1);
set(vid, 'ReturnedColorSpace', 'RGB');
img = getsnapshot(vid);
disp(size(img))
imshow(img)
```

Python 3

```
from cv2 import *
# initialize the camera
cam = VideoCapture(0)   # 0 -> index of camera
s, img = cam.read()
print(img.shape)
if s:    # frame captured without any errors
    namedWindow("cam-test")
    imwrite("filename.jpg", img)  # save image
    imshow("cam-test",img)
    waitKey(0)
    destroyWindow("cam-test")
```